Obtaining the subtraction of circular paths in TikZ
I have the following figure.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\radA{2.0cm}
\def\radB{2.8cm}

\coordinate[label=left:A] (A) at (0, 0);
\coordinate[label=left:B] (B) at (0, 1.4);

\path[draw,name path=CA] (A) circle (\radA);
\path[draw,name path=CB] (B) circle (\radB);

\foreach \i in {A,B} {
  \filldraw[black] (\i) circle (0.4pt);
}

\path[name intersections={of=CA and CB, by={[label=above:$I1$]I1, [label=below:$I2$]I2}}];

\draw[fill=black!80] (I1) circle (1pt);
\draw[fill=black!80] (I2) circle (1pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The problem here is that I have to color fill the circle path CA that falls outside of circle path CB, thus also the area defined by two intersecting circular arcs. I guess there would be at least two ways to obtain the area.

By subtracting the path B from path A (CA-CB) and filling the remaining path.
By drawing arcs that pass through the intersection points on the circles with given radius.

I would prefer the second method if anyone could show me how to calculate the start and end angles for the arcs with the given set of points. Thankfully.


With ext.paths.arcto library
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.arcto}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\radA{2.0cm}
\def\radB{2.8cm}

\coordinate[label=left:A] (A) at (0, 0);
\coordinate[label=left:B] (B) at (0, 1.4);

\path[draw,name path=CA] (A) circle (\radA);
\path[draw,name path=CB] (B) circle (\radB);

\foreach \i in {A,B} {
  \filldraw[black] (\i) circle (0.4pt);
}

\path[name intersections={of=CA and CB, by={[label=above:$I1$]I1, [label=below:$I2$]I2}}];

\draw[fill=black!80] (I1) circle (1pt);
\draw[fill=black!80] (I2) circle (1pt);

\draw[blue,fill=blue!50] (I1) arc to[radius=\radB,large,clockwise](I2)
arc to[radius=\radA,large](I1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Much obliged! Actually I wanted to shade the other way around which was possible after tinkering with the code you provided: \draw[blue,fill=blue!50] (I1) arc to[radius=\radA](I2) arc to[radius=\radB,clockwise](I1) ;.
